# Change the user role after x days

Tags: user-roles

Is there a way to change back the user role after `x` days? When people register at my site, they have an 2 options to choose: `seller` or `customer`. I want to put an additional user role `member1`, and if I make them user role `member1`, after 14 days the user role should automatically change back to their default user role (either `seller` or `customer`). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea that you can implement. I think it will work just fine.

1. Save the expiration time in user meta. Say the meta name is `change_role`. What you save in the meta is unix time. If you want to change them back in 14 days. Set the meta value to `time() + 60 * 60 * 24 *14`

**code example** `update_user_meta($user_id, 'change_role', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 *14);`

2. Register a [wp cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) to search for expired accounts and change their roles back. Run the cron every hour or so. The search query will search for users who have the `change_role` meta value less then the current unix timestamp value.

**Code Example**

The cron function may look like this.

```
function change_expired_users_role(){
    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'change_role',
        'meta_value' => time(),
        'meta_compare' => `<=`,
        'fields' => array('ID')
    );

    $users = get_users($args);

    if(empty($users))
        return;

    foreach($users as $user){
       // change user role
       // delete the user meta
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.