# Remove role of user after X days

Tags: php, functions

I have issues getting this code to work. I want to `BUGSexpdate` which has a set date to remove a role when the date is reached as I want to "rent" out movies. This code I found on a similar thread does not work.

[Change the user role after x days](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194971/change-the-user-role-after-x-days)

```php
add_action( 'change_expired_users_hook', 'change_expired_users_role' );

function change_expired_users_role(){
    $args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'BUGSexpdate',
    'meta_value' => time(),
    'meta_compare' => `<=`,
    'fields' => array('ID')
    );

    $users = get_users($args);

    if( empty( $users ) )
        return;

    foreach( $users as $user ){
        
        // Remove old role
        $user->remove_role( 'bugs' ); 

        // Add new role
        $user->add_role( 'customer' );
                
    }
}
```

Comment: there's no information about what `BUGSexpdate` contains and the format of the data, and it doesn't look like you've confirmed if it finds the users or not. Your cron job registration is also missing too so it's not possible to check if the problem is there. What is `BUGSexpdate` exactly? If it does not do what you want it to do, what does it do instead?

Comment: Guess you could work with transient's, if False: user doesn't have the movie anymore.
https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/

Comment: BUGSexpdate is the expiry date that get puts into the user meta when purchasing, it is the current date + 7 days.